# How do I append numpy arrays along a new axis or dimension without flattening

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

If given a list or numpy array of the same dimensions and length defined as

```
lista = [5,2,5,...]
listb = [5,1,8,...]
listc = [1,7,8,...]
listd = [1,0,5,...]
liste = [1,2,1,...]
listf = [9,1,8,...]
```

How do I get a multidimensional array with an output where the fist index is grouped and put into a multidimensional array?

```
resulting_list = [[[5,2,5,...], [5,1,8,...]],
                  [[1,7,8,...], [1,0,5,...], [1,2,1,...]],
                  [[9,1,8,...]]]
```

My solution to this was a for loop but I have been largely unsuccessful, use of numpy.append, numpy.concatenate, numpy.vstack, etc has been unsuccessful.

here is one of my example solutions, it should be noted that the lists are **always** initially grouped (but not necessarily ranked as its not needed) with the first index in a single stack in an array.

```
#Data
lista = np.array([5,2,5])
listb = np.array([5,1,8])
listc = np.array([1,7,8])
listd = np.array([1,0,5])
liste = np.array([1,2,1])
listf = np.array([9,1,8])

list_index = np.vstack((lista, listb, listc, listd, liste, listf))

result_list = lista

for i in range(4):
    if list_index[i][0] == list_index[i+1][0]:
       result_list = np.append(result_list, list_index[i+1], axis=0)
    else:
        result_list = np.append(result_list, list_index[i+1], axis=1)

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Generally I am having issues appending these lists to a new dimensions or along a specific axis.

Comment: Could you not just do `return_list = [lista, listb, listc, listd, liste, listf]` ?

Comment: the first index are identifiers they have to be separated as a future function will process the return_list.

Comment: `np.append` is just a another way to call to `np.concatenate` (with flattening if you don't provide axis).  Repeated use of any of these `stack/concatante` in a loop is a bad idea.  Do the grouping with list methods first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is the following:

```
>>> lists = [lista, listb, listc, listd, liste, listf]
>>> first_vals = {x[0] for x in lists}    # unique first element values
>>> res = [np.array([x for x in lists if x[0] == v]) for v in first_vals]
>>> res
[array([[1, 7, 8],
        [1, 0, 5],
        [1, 2, 1]]),
 array([[5, 2, 5],
        [5, 1, 8]]),
 array([[9, 1, 8]])]
```

This gives a list of 2-dimensional arrays grouped by the first element. You can convert the whole thing into an array with `dtype=object` (since the 2D arrays generally have different shapes), but I really see no point in doing so.

Comment: What a concise solution to something I struggled with for a long time, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not as concise as the accepted answer, but closer in style to what you were trying to do.  Mainly I am collecting rows in lists, rather than using array appends.  List append is easier to use, and faster.

```
In [119]: lista = np.array([5,2,5]) 
     ...: listb = np.array([5,1,8]) 
     ...: listc = np.array([1,7,8]) 
     ...: listd = np.array([1,0,5]) 
     ...: liste = np.array([1,2,1]) 
     ...: listf = np.array([9,1,8]) 
     ...:  
     ...: lists = [lista, listb, listc, listd, liste, listf]
```

Collect values in a list of lists:

```
In [126]: result_list = [] 
     ...: alist = []; first = lists[0][0] 
     ...: for row in lists: 
     ...:     if row[0]==first: 
     ...:         alist.append(row) 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         result_list.append(alist) 
     ...:         alist = [row]; first = row[0] 
     ...: result_list.append(alist)                                                                    

In [127]: result_list                                                                                  
Out[127]: 
[[array([5, 2, 5]), array([5, 1, 8])],
 [array([1, 7, 8]), array([1, 0, 5]), array([1, 2, 1])],
 [array([9, 1, 8])]]
```

optionally convert the inner lists to arrays:

```
In [128]: [np.vstack(x) for x in result_list]                                                          
Out[128]: 
[array([[5, 2, 5],
        [5, 1, 8]]), array([[1, 7, 8],
        [1, 0, 5],
        [1, 2, 1]]), array([[9, 1, 8]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.stack()` is probably what you're looking for, which joins a sequence of (numpy) arrays along a new axis.
Here is an example from [this NumPy page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):
`a = np.array([1, 2, 3])`
`b = np.array([4, 5, 6])`
`np.stack((a, b))`
`>> array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])`